# Read and write properties using config parser in Python script

Tags: python

I am trying to read a property from properties file and if it is not there, i need to add that property to properties file

Following is my script

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('test.properties')

ip = config.get('client', 'primaryIp')
print "ip is " +ip

if not ip:
    Config.set('client','primaryIp','10.31.1.143')
```

But it throws the following error at line " ip = config.get('client', 'primaryIp') "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    ip = config.get('client', 'primaryIp')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 340, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'primaryIp' in section: 'client'
```

How could i avoid this exception

Answer (score 2):

Use [try except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions) to catch you exception if there is any.

It's a simple concept if you have the option `primaryIp` then everything is ok, but if you have an `NoOptionError` then you need to set the option since it's not present in the file:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('test.properties')

try:
    ip = config.get('client', 'primaryIp')
    print "ip is " +ip
except NoOptionError:
    config.set('client','primaryIp','10.31.1.143')
```

Comment: Executing the above script throws the following exception,Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    except NoOptionError:
NameError: name 'NoOptionError' is not defined

Comment: When i modified it to except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:, it executed successfully, but primaryIp property is not written to test.properties

Comment: You fix is current or you can `from ConfigParser import NoOptionError`, as for the `set` you need to write it to the file from the `config` object with something like `config.write(configfile)`